# Redirect someone from broken links to an index page without .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Users will try entering the following links http://product-meta-tools.lm.son.se/itool/ and other links derived from this one i.e. http://product-meta-tools.lm.son.se/itool/randomPage.php. These pages no longer exist. I want to redirect from these broken links to a different project on the server e.g http://product-meta-tools.lm.son.se/ytool/index.php.

I've read up stuff about changing htaccess to redirect but I do not have privileges to change this file on the linux server I am working on. What other viable ways are there to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this including the .htaccess file you mentioned. That said, the .htaccess requires the fewest/lowest permissions. If you do not have access to make a .htaccess file, then you won't have access to do any of the others.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all 404 links to `http://example.com/ytool/index.php` ,you can use the following `ErrorDocument` in htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/ytool/index.php
```